# Not possible to enter name/email to post an answer when not logged in

Tags: support, status-bydesign, login, beta

If you're not logged in, and attempt to post an answer, SU will prompt for an OpenID url, but the red text under that says:

> You must provide name and email, or
>   your OpenID

I don't see any way to provide anything but OpenID url.

Answer (score 4):

superuser does not allow anonymous participation during the private beta. You must use an openid.